# EnumDropDownListFor and removing select title

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using   EnumDropDownListFor helper for rending dropdown with enums, ofcourse.

```
 @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.MyProperty, "Select", new { @class = "combobox form-control" })
```

When `model.MyProperty` does not have value drop down has `Select` as first item, which I don't want to appear as select option, so I tried with

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.MyProperty, null, new { @class = "combobox form-control" })
```

but now I cannot open dropdown at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `null` instead of a string may causes your code to call some other `EnumDropDownListFor` overload, have you checked your are still calling the one you believe?
The drop down should still have the enum values as options list.

You may try instead:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyProperty,
    EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(YourEnum)),
    new { @class = "combobox form-control" })
```

In your resulting html, it should look like:

```html
<select name="MyProperty" id="MyProperty">
   <option value="FirstEnumValue">FirstEnumLabel</option>
   <option value="SecondEnumValue">SecondEnumLabel</option>
   ...
</select>
```

By the way, in most browsers, it will by default select the first non disabled option instead of staying blank as you are probably expecting. You may overcome this with JavaScript, by explicitly setting its value to some invalid value (invalid in regards to your enum values list).

If, by the same time, you want your select to be mandatory (`required` attribute), you then ask something forbidden by [html spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element).

> If a select element has a required attribute specified, does not have
>   a multiple attribute specified, and has a [display size](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-select-size) of 1, then the
>   select element must have a [placeholder label option](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#placeholder-label-option).

And the spec defines it as:

> If a select element has a required attribute specified, does not have
>   a multiple attribute specified, and has a [display size](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-select-size) of 1; and if
>   the value of the first option element in the select element's list of
>   options (if any) is the empty string, and that option element's parent
>   node is the select element (and not an optgroup element), then that
>   option is the select element's **placeholder label option**.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.MyProperty, new { @class = "combobox form-control" })
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/dn550750(v=vs.118).aspx)

**EDIT:**

If you don't want to make the default text as a select option, use `javascript` to make the option disabled.

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.MyProperty, "Select...", new { @class = "combobox form-control" })
```

However, there seems to be no way to add attributes to a `SelectListItem`.

```
<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName("option")[0].disabled = true;
</script>
```

Comment: What do you want to display if **model.MyProperty** doesn't have value?